# Jrebel is not working with weblogic 12.X

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c, jrebel

**Issue Description:**
Unable to bounce the weblogic server with JRebel

**Error:**
I am getting the follwoing error when i try to bounce the server

```
JRebel: ERROR Class 'java.lang.ClassLoader' could not be processed by com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.bv@null: org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.bytecode.DuplicateMemberException: duplicate method: _jr$defineClass in java.lang.ClassLoader
        at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.bytecode.ClassFile.testExistingMethod(SourceFile:721)
        at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.bytecode.ClassFile.addMethod(SourceFile:696)
        at org.zeroturnaround.bundled.javassist.CtClassType.addMethod(SourceFile:1411)
        at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.bv.process(SourceFile:40)
        at org.zeroturnaround.javarebel.integration.support.JavassistClassBytecodeProcessor.process(SourceFile:79)
        at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.vu.a(SourceFile:376)
        at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.vu.a(SourceFile:365)
        at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.vu.a(SourceFile:350)
        at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.f.runBootClassProcessors(SourceFile:245)
        at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.bl.a(SourceFile:115)
        at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.gib.a(SourceFile:63)
        at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.gfc.a(SourceFile:59)
        at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.gfc.doTransform(SourceFile:39)
        at com.zeroturnaround.jrebelbase.reorder.a.transform(SourceFile:182)
        at com.zeroturnaround.jrebelbase.reorder.a.transform(SourceFile:148)
        at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(InstrumentationImpl.java)
        at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.redefineClasses0(Native Method)
        at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.redefineClasses(InstrumentationImpl.java:170)
        at com.mercury.opal.capture.jdk15.agent.ProbeClassFileTransformer.instrumentAndReplace(ProbeClassFileTransformer.java:369)
        at com.mercury.opal.capture.jdk15.agent.ProbeClassFileTransformer.reinstrumentClass(ProbeClassFileTransformer.java:331)
        at com.mercury.opal.capture.jdk15.agent.ProbeClassFileTransformer.patchClassLoaders(ProbeClassFileTransformer.java:137)
        at com.mercury.opal.capture.jdk15.agent.ProbeClassFileTransformer.<init>(ProbeClassFileTransformer.java:98)
        at com.mercury.opal.capture.jdk15.agent.InstrumentationAgent.premain(InstrumentationAgent.java:66)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.__invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl._jrLoadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:386)
        at com.zeroturnaround.jrebelbase.reorder.b.a(SourceFile:31)
        at com.zeroturnaround.jrebelbase.reorder.a.c(SourceFile:129)
        at com.zeroturnaround.jrebelbase.reorder.a.a(SourceFile:118)
        at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.gec.a(SourceFile:309)
        at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.gec.deferredInitHook(SourceFile:149)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java)
```

**Config Details :**

following lines in startup script based on the Jrebel root folder

```
export REBEL_HOME=[JRebel root folder]
export JAVA_OPTIONS="-agentpath:$REBEL_HOME/lib/libjrebel64.so -Drebel.remoting_plugin=true $JAVA_OPTIONS"
```

**Version:**

Weblogic : 12.2.1.2.0

Jrebel : 7.1.2

Can anyone help me to come over?

Comment: Have you managed to resolve the issue by now?

Comment: `com.mercury.opal.capture.jdk15.agent.ProbeClassFileTransformer` sounds like part of an instrumentation agent which is causing a conflict. Generally compatibility with other agents is not guaranteed, but newer versions have had improvements.

Answer (score 4):

Please try using the latest version of JRebel instead of **7.1.2**. Download it at https://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/download/prev-releases/.

If for some reason the result is still the same, also delete **REBEL_HOME/bootcache** and retry. Should you *still* see the exception, please write to support@zeroturnaround.com along with the **jrebel.log** from **REBEL_HOME** and they'll be able to help you out.